# Why does this filter no longer work in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm upgrading a project from Django 1.8 to Django 2.1.3 (yes, I know I should update more, but that's the client requirement at this point).

The exact same models.py file and exact same Django ORM query in the views.py file are in both (Python3 updates notwithstanding), the Django 1.8 version works fine but with Django 2.1.3, this filter (which worked perfectly fine with Django 1.8):

```
kwargs['car__carcategory__category__category_id'] = categoryId
```

is now producing the following error with Django 2.1.3:

```
raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: carcategory
```

Here is the query:

```
cars = CarModel.objects.only(

'car__car_id',

'car__cardate',

'car__title',

'car__location',

'car__quote',

'car__key',

'car__cartype_id',

'maker__lastname',

'maker__firstname',

'maker__middlename',

'maker__nickname',

).select_related(

'car',

'maker',

).extra(

select={

'is_position_paper': 'cartype_id = 7',

'is_null_date': 'cardate IS NULL',

'shorttitle': extra,

},

).filter(**kwargs).distinct(sort_order_for_distinct, 'car__car_id').order_by(sort_order, 'car__car_id')
```

Here are the relevant models:

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    car_candidate_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    partsmanufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'car_model'


class Car(models.Model):
    car_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cartype = models.ForeignKey(Cartype, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cardate = models.DateField(null=True)
        db_table = u'car'


class Carcategory(models.Model):
    car_category_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'car_category'
```

Anybody know what gives here? What was changed or deprecated in terms of being to do this Django 1.8 but now no longer in a slightly new Django version?

The DB is the same, nothing's been changed there, and like I said, the models.py file is exactly the same (aside from updating some ForeignKey fields with on_delete=models.CASCADE for the Django 2.1.3 version)

Comment: The exception suggests that you wrote `car__car_category__category__category_id` (so with an underscore between `car` and `category`, whereas it should be `car__carcategory__category__category_id`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my mistake, fixed typo in post.

Comment: you did not specify a `related_query_name` or `related_name` in the `car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But if you don't provide a value for `related_name` or `default_related_name`, doesn't it just default to the name of the model?

Comment: Anyway, I added it to the field: 

`car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_query_name="car_category")`

It makes no difference, still the same error. Was something deprecated after Django 1.8 or thereabouts wherein it's no longer possible to use a filter with these relations in this way?